# Java Socket - Connection Reset in Server to Client when Client connects to Server

Tags: java, client, serversocket

So I'm trying to set up a Client <-> Server connection. I keep getting the most annoying error because the client and server will not connect but only send "cpc" once when I call

```
print("cpc");
```

This is the code which I am using. This is contained in a class which extends Thread.

```
BufferedReader in = null;
out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
String inputLine, outputLine;
print("cpc");
try{
    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        outputLine = process(inputLine);
        if (!outputLine.equals("")){
            print(outputLine);
        }

    }
} catch (Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

There error is where 'while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {' is located.
Here is the error if any of you need it.

```
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(Unknown Source)
at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(Unknown Source)
at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(Unknown Source)
at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
at javaclient.Client.run(Client.java:28)
```

**Heres the print() code**

```
public void print(String s){
    out.println(s);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

<strike>You are reading lines but you aren't sending lines. Try println() instead of print().</strike>
The most usual cause of 'connection reset' is that you have written to a connection which had already been closed by the peer. You usually get it not on that write but on a subsequent read or write. Basically it is an application protocol error.

Comment: print() is a function. Edited post.